# changing html in Galauness template

Tags: html, templates, blogger

acausedesbrunettes.com and I am trying to change the HTML code for the navigation bar (home - category) into the individual pages "events" "fashion" "food" "travel" so that my posts using the #events, #fashion, #food, #travel appear on these individual pages. Can anyone help me in how I have to entry this in the template's HTML?

I would also like for the thumbnails to be bigger; how can I adjust this? 
And if you place your mouse on a post you see the "comments" section, I would also want to delete this so that the text of the post istelf only shows.

Answer (score 0):

To change the navigation bar, you'll want to use your WordPress admin area, instead of changing HTML code (you could change the HTML code, but you would have to dig and dig to find where it is in the PHP files in your site's directory). Hover over "Appearance" and select "Menus".

For the size of thumbnails, use CSS in the style.css file (hopefully you're using a child theme).  And to remove comments, try a plugin called "disable comments".

Comment: Hopefully this isn't confusing to you!  If so, you will have to learn a bit about WordPress first in order to apply these things.